# Issue using a variable with an r-string in Python

Tags: python, pandas

Fairly new to Python, and I've got a batch job that I now have to start saving some extracts from out to a company Sharepoint site.  I've searched around and cannot seem to find a solution to the issue I keep running into.  I need to pass a date into the filename, and was first having issues with using a normal string.  If I just type out the entire thing as a raw string, I get the output I want:

```
x =  r"\\mnt4793\DavWWWRoot\sites\GlobalSupply\Plastics\DataExtracts\2021-02-15_aRoute.xlsx"
      
print (x)
```

The output is: *\mnt4793\DavWWWRoot\sites\GlobalSupply\Plastics\DataExtracts\2021-02-15_aRoute.xlsx*

However, if I break the string into it's parts so I can get a parameter in there, I wind up having to toss an extra double-quote on the "x" parameter to keep the code from running into a **"SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal"** error:

```
x =  r"\\mnt4793\DavWWWRoot\sites\GlobalSupply\Plastics\DataExtracts\""
timestamp = date_time_obj.date().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
filename = "_aRoute.xlsx"
      
print (x + timestamp + filename)
```

But the output I get passes that unwanted double quote into my string: *\mnt4793\DavWWWRoot\sites\GlobalSupply\Plastics\DataExtracts"2021-02-15_aRoute.xlsx*

The syntax I need is clearly escaping me, I'm just trying to get the path built so I can save the file itself.  If it happens to matter, I'm using pandas to write the file:

```
data = pandas.read_sql(sql, cnxn)
data.to_excel(string_goes_here)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You have a typo. You have two double quotes at the end of the first string. Should only be one with raw strings.

Comment: you are trying to create a filename it seems. why dont you try [pathlib join operator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#operators) or [pathlib joinpath](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.joinpath)

Comment: @RobertJacobs, I did try that, but without that second set of double quotes I get the following error: "SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal"

Comment: @sammywemmy thank you for the link! I will look into it.

Comment: Even a r-string can't end with only one backslash. CIte from [String and Bytes literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals): "even a raw string cannot end in an odd number of backslashes". Evil workaround: `r'\\server\whatever' +'\\'`.

Comment: @Matthias Worked like a charm!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the comment from @Matthias, as it turns out, an r-string can't end with a single backslash.  The quick workaround, therefore, was:

```
x =  r"\\mnt4793\DavWWWRoot\sites\GlobalSupply\Plastics\DataExtracts" + "\\"
```

The comment from @sammywemmy also linked to what looks to be a much more thorough solution.

Thank you both!